# T-Value And Significance (SLR in R)

Tags: regression

I am currently trying to figure out the output I got from the summary-command when I do a linear regression in R.
I get 2 values that I do not understand, first: the t-value. I do understand that it uses a t-test, testing the null hypothesis H0: coef = 0. But I do not understand what it means, plus I do not understand what the value means.
Then there's Pr(|>t|) which apparently is the Significance of my coefficient, and I still don't know what that means.
The problem is I do not need detailed math on this, this I why I gave up on wikipedia. I just need a general understanding, so maybe someone can help me out?